# Impossible to resolve dependencies in Ivy

Tags: ivy

I met a weird thing. I use ivy retrieve tag to put jar to somewhere.If I write code like below:

```
    <target name="test">
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[artifact](.[ext])" sync="true" type="jar" conf="webInfLib"/>
    </target>
```

It work fine. But if I add something like below:

```
    <target name="test">
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy.path" />
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[artifact](.[ext])" sync="true" type="jar" conf="webInfLib"/>
    </target>
```

It will throw "impossible to resolve dependencies". Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need the "sync" and "type" attributes on the retrieve task?

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce your problem. What version of ivy are using?

## Example

Used the following software versions:

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2
Apache Ivy 2.3.0-rc2
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="build" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <target name="init" description="Use ivy to resolve classpaths">
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="ivy.path" />
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[artifact](.[ext])" sync="true" type="jar" conf="webInfLib"/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="init" description="build project">
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="Cleanup build files">
        <delete dir="lib"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="Additionally purge ivy cache">
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

</project>
```

### ivy.xml

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="webInfLib"  description="add jar to web-inf/lib folder"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="javax.servlet" name="servlet-api" rev="2.4" conf="webInfLib->default"/>
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```